# What was the first translation to transliterate the tetragrammaton?

Tags: bible-translation, tetragrammaton

Some Christians today like to transliterate the Tetragrammaton into their modern language translations, and to pronounce the name when reading aloud (their best reconstruction of the name I mean, usually "Yahweh".) Other Christians oppose this, saying that it goes against centuries and even millenia of Jewish and Christian practice.

So I'd like to know what was the earliest translation of the Hebrew scriptures which attempted to transliterate the Tetragrammaton?

Answers should not be limited to English translations, but they should only give translations which frequently use a transliteration. For example, see [Wikipedia for translations which use "Jehovah"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehovah#Usage_in_English_Bible_translations). The KJV's seven uses of "Jehovah" is not the kind of translation I'm asking about; Young's Literal Translation (published 1862) with 6831 uses of "Jehovah" is.

(Aparently the [formal definition of "transliteration"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration) is strictly a one to one mapping, with "transcription" refers to trying to write the sounds ignoring silent or double letters etc. In my experience "transcription" is colloquially called "transliteration". But it probably doesn't make a difference for the Tetragrammaton.)

Comment: Be sure to specify whether you are looking for a translation (finding an equivalent in a target language for a word in the source language: 'the Lord') vs. transLITeration (inscribing a word in the source into a target language as close as you can into the other language by using the equivalent letters if this is possible, but disregarding the meaning it had in the original language: e.g. 'yhvh').

Comment: @Sola I think it's quite clear that I'm asking about transliterations of the Tetragrammaton. Though the Septuagint mimicking letter shapes regardless of sound is a further complication.

Comment: I see. Good luck with your question.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that the Septuagint may be the first translation of the ancient Hebrew scriptures to have retained YHWH. Although retaining the Hebrew form of this word is not a transliteration, please bear with me as I explain what happened.

In the time of Ptolomaic rule over Judea (320 to 198 B.C.) many Greek people came in to Judea, their culture influencing the people. This hellenization resulted in a Greek translation of the Hebrew scriptures. It began to be written around 285 B.C. and was finished during the 100s B.C. The Septuagint became the scriptures for Greek speaking Jews of the first century A.D. and the apostle Paul used it when quoting from the Hebrew scriptures, though he never kept the Hebrew YHWH, but wrote Greek for ‘Lord’. This is significant when Paul quoted Hebrew text referring to Yahweh but applied it to Jesus Christ. This was a transliteration. Was it the earliest, the first?

From this link below the claim is made that,

> “In the earliest manuscripts of the Septuagint the Tetragrammaton was
>   given in Hebrew letters, which in Greek circles were supposed to be
>   Greek and were read πιπι (Field, "Origenis Hexaplorum Quæ Supersunt,"
>   i. 90, Oxford, 1875; Herzog-Hauck, l.c. viii. 530; Blau, l.c. p.
>   131).” 
>   http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14346-tetragrammaton

I have no knowledge of whether those earliest manuscripts of the Septuagint were actually Greek and were read πιπι, or not. However, if they were, then that would be a transliteration.

According to the link below, there are ancient Greek manuscripts, such as the Septuagint, proto-masoretic, kaige, translation by Aquila of Sinope, Symmachus the Ebionite, Theodotion and the Hexapla [written by Origen in the first half of the third century A.D.] that contain the Hebrew YHWH or that have it in paleo-Hebrew script. Those would not be transliterations.

However, it is important to note that that particular manuscript fragment in the entry below is a REVISION of the Septuagint, so that the Septuagint original will pre-date it.
It adds that there is a book on this written by Emanuel Tov in 1990: Discoveries in the Judean Desert: VIII. The Greek Minor Prophets Scroll from Nahal Hever (8HevXIIgr). Oxford: Clarendon Press. ISBN 978-0-198263272 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_Minor_Prophets_Scroll_from_Nahal_Hever

Now, your question asks about earliest transliterations of the Hebrew Tetragrammaton, yet I have written about retaining the Hebrew, not transliterations of it (apart from the possibility of a transliteration into Greek in the link http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/14346-tetragrammaton

This is where my final link is of significance.

> The Septuagint represents the first major effort at translating a
>   significant religious text from one language into another. It is
>   interesting to note that many of the New Testament quotes from the
>   Hebrew Bible are taken from the Septuagint. As faithful as the
>   Septuagint translators strived to be in accurately rendering the
>   Hebrew text into Greek, some translational differences arose. In
>   comparing the New Testament quotations of the Hebrew Bible, it is
>   clear that the Septuagint was often used. This is the result of the
>   fact that by the late 1st century B.C., and especially the 1st century
>   A.D. – the Septuagint had “replaced” the Hebrew Bible as the
>   Scriptures most people used. Since most people spoke and read Greek as
>   their primary language, and the Greek authorities strongly encouraged
>   the use of Greek, the Septuagint became much more common than the
>   Hebrew Old Testament. The fact that the Apostles and New Testament
>   authors felt comfortable, under the direction of the Holy Spirit, in
>   using the Septuagint should give us assurance that a translation of
>   the original languages of the Bible is still the authoritative Word of
>   God.

http://www.gotquestion.org/YHWH.html

Please note how the apostle Paul transliterated his quotations from the Hebrew scriptures where the Tetragrammaton occurred, into the Greek word for ‘Lord’.

Obviously, if another answer gives evidence of the Tetragrammaton being transliterated in manuscripts predating Paul’s writings (all completed before A.D. 70), then my answer will need to be corrected.

Comment: "Please note how the apostle Paul transliterated his quotations from the Hebrew scriptures where the Tetragrammaton occurred, into the Greek word for ‘Lord’." I don't understand in what sense you can call this a transliteration.

Comment: @ curiousdannii - Translation is one thing, transliteration is another thing, and pronunciation is yet another thing. The Hebrew letters YHWH may be translated into, say, Greek language, going from the original language to another. Then, if that Greek translation is written down as another word (either in the Greek or in another language) it becomes a transliteration. My answer deals with that and not with pronunciation. Hope that helps!

Comment: @curiousdannii - Transliteration is required when there is no exact equivalent word in a language which the original text is being translated into.  The purpose of transliterating a word is to deal with the problem of there being no attached meaning in the new language. An example is the Hebrew word 'debir' (which Solomon built). When the Septuagint turned that into Greek, it used 'dabir' but as there is no such Greek word, nor is that similar to anything in Greek, it is a transliteration and not a translation. No equivalent Greek word suffices for the Hebrew 'debir'. Again, I hope this helps.

Comment: I know what transliteration is. I don't see how turning יהוה into κύριος could in any sense be called a transliteration. But that seems to be what you were claiming Paul did.

Comment: There is no exact equivalent word for the Hebrew YHWH in any language, for this is unique to Hebrew. This means that in a translation, either the Hebrew is retained (which is not a translation at that point) or the nearest equivalent in the new language is used (a transliteration) so every time another word is used (e.g. Jehovah) that is a transliteration and not a translation. Paul used the Greek 'Adonay' (Lord) and 'Theos' (God) as the best words to signify the Creator God.

Comment: A transliteration has to have some semblance of the same sounds. Adonai is Hebrew not Greek, but neither it nor Kurious, nor Theos, are in any way transliterations of YHWH.

Comment: Correct, insofar as Paul did not try to put YHWH into a new word. He stuck to the Greek for Lord and God because there was no way those 4 Hebrew letters could be rendered in Greek. He substituted YHWH with Lord/God, whilst translating the Hebrew for Lord/God (when quoting those words) with Greek translations. He did not coin a new word for YHWH as happened centuries later when a Catholic scholar, working from Latin into German, came up with Jehova. When ‘J’ was later added to the English alphabet in the early 1500s, some wrote Jehovah. Both those words are transliterations.

Comment: However, I would add that pronunciation has to do with the sound of words. Those two transliterations attempt to produce new words that sound similar to YHWH but the breathy 'Yahweh' seems closer in sound.

Comment: So why did you say that Paul was using a transliteration when he used the Greek for lord (kurious)???

Comment: There’s no real difference between substituting a word and transliterating it. A transliterated word is a form of substitute word. I use those interchangeably. Perhaps I’m wrong. But certainly Paul had such respect for the Divine Name (in Hebrew) that he would not coin a new word (in Greek), sticking to the accepted Lord God for the Creator as a safe substitute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81270/discussion-between-curiousdannii-and-anne).

Comment: I can't use chat - it doesn't open up to me. All I will add is that I have never agreed at any point that transliteration is about pronunciation - getting another word that sounds like the original one. That is not what transliteration is. We have crossed wires about what transliteration means but I will leave it at that, if you don't mind.

Comment: Sorry but I do mind. You don't get to make up meanings, which is what I think you're doing here. But maybe not, and other people do use it your way. Can you please provide a source that supports your definition of transliteration, if there's a subset of the world that is using the word differently then we can at least trace the source of the confusion.

Comment: This is my final comment. I am not here to debate or to chat. I have offered an answer but if you disagree with all or part of it, that's fine by me.  I am open to being corrected by reading answers that are better than mine, that show where I'm wrong, but comments and chat only lead to arguments and I abhor that. I hope someone else provides a more satisfactory answer for you.  All the best.

Comment: There are lots of sources I could suggest which give my definition of transliteration, [here's one](http://www.londontranslations.co.uk/faq/basics/what-is-a-transliteration-and-how-is-it-different-to-a-translation/): "Transliteration is the process of expressing the sound of how a word is pronounced in the source language in the alphabet of the target language." All I'd like from you is one source that says that Paul turning יהוה into κύριος, which has no sounds nor letters in common, is a transliteration. You have given **no supporting evidence** for your claim! Please [edit] this to do so.

Comment: I’m confused about Hebrew characters being in Greek manuscripts. I’m a novice at Greek so correct me if I’m wrong, but isn’t it necessary for all proper nouns to be placed in the correct case ending in order for the sentence to be intelligible? How would that would with the hebrew name YHWH in it?

Comment: @diego b The Divine Name is a special case and had no Greek equivalent, as I understand but I'm not qualified to answer your question. I suggest you ask your question as a post in the Stack Hermeneutics site as people who know about biblical Hebrew and Greek are active there. All I can do is quote from authorities, as I did in my answer, so I cannot add anything further. I hope you make progress with your question.